# Specify which properties DataAnnotationsValidator should validate

Tags: blazor

I am having a razor component with an `EditForm` and `DataAnnotationsValidator`. The form has input fields for one property, but my model has two properties that are required. Is it possible to specify exactly properties that should be validated? I could of course assign the property a value in code, but it would be nice to avoid that.

My code looks like this:

```
@page "/counter"

<EditForm EditContext="@_editContext">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="_model.Name" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.Name)" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    class MyModel
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    private EditContext _editContext;
    private MyModel _model = new MyModel();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(_model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add [Write(false)] to elements you don't want to validate (it must also not need to be writted to the db though of course and may not be relevant

Answer (score 1):

The DataAnnotations validation support for Blazor is designed to work against both the form field AND the overall model in the edit context. You can extend the validation behavior per the instructions [in the documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-support)

**EDIT** 
One way that this can still work is to ***omit*** the line `<ValidationSummary />` inside the `EditForm` component, and keep the individual `<ValidationMessage />` for each form field. You lose the overall summary, but it will work.

Alternatively you can also restrict the Context down in your initialized method to `_editContext = new EditContext(_model.Name);` so you are only considering the Name property in the edit context, however this will throw a null reference exception unless you also set up your `MyModel.Name` property to initialize to an empty string like so: `public string Name { get; set; } = "";`. In this case you should add another data annotation to `Name` to specify a minimum length to make sure the user still has to enter something.

Perhaps the bigger question is if the email address is required, why aren't you capturing it in the form also? Conversely, if you don't need to capture it, why include it in the model?

A simpler option for this use case is to restrict your model just what you are working with directly. If you really must get around the validation on the Email property, remember that the `DataAnnotations` that you are decorating your properties with are designed to work with some form of validation. You may be better off using a Data transfer object in the context of this form only that captures *only* what you need at this time, such as the Name property, and then assigning it to a larger model as appropriate through a programmatic Set method after you have validated it, rather than something that runs the validation. This of course defeats the purpose of the annotation to begin with, so give it some thought as to what makes the most sense. That's up to you.

Comment: One scenario where you get this problem is when you have data model from the database with information that should not be visible in the UI. You could also have different forms where the user edits parts of the data model. Creating multiple models will solve this problem, but this will also create new ones as you mentioned :-/

Comment: Understood. I added one edit that you may have tried already or would prefer not to use, but in the interest of a complete answer I thought I should add it.